# GCDASyncSocket SSL don't connect

Tags: ios, cocoa, sockets, ssl, tcpclient

I had my socket connection working, but the server was updated to SSL. I call this method:

```
[socket startTLS:nil];
```

Bu I still can't make a secure connection with the server. I initiate the connection like this:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];

    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![socket connectToHost:@"192.168.2.210" onPort:1333 viaInterface:@"" withTimeout:-1 error:&err]) // Asynchronous!
    {
            // If there was an error, it's likely something like "already connected" or "no delegate set"
        NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connecting...");
    }
    [socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];

}
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the [socket startTLS:nil] after make the initNetworkCommunication, but it should be at the moment that we make the connection, like this:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];

    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![socket connectToHost:@"192.168.2.210" onPort:1333 viaInterface:@"" withTimeout:-1 error:&err]) // Asynchronous!
    {
            // If there was an error, it's likely something like "already connected" or "no delegate set"
        NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);
    }else
    {
        [socket startTLS:nil];
        NSLog(@"Connecting...");

        }
        [socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];

}
```